# Re-sizing tables to fit the screen

Tags: c#, asp.net, code-behind

I have some ASP.NET website and I'm coding two `Table`'s from its codebehind file and I try to have them both in the same line. It does work with my PC when I check it but it won't work in other devices of other size. The second table then goes down because it has no much space. I used percentages to set the table width so I have no idea why it's not working in other devices the same.. This is the part of my code that generates the tables:

```
else if (level >= CMD.PList && (string)Request.QueryString["action"] == "plist")
{
    int count = 0;
    DataSet data = Database.GetDataOffline("SELECT * FROM " + Database.Table + " WHERE " + Database.Adminlvl + "> 0 ORDER BY " + Database.Adminlvl + " DESC, " + Database.ID + " ASC");
    oac.InnerHtml += "<table style='width:47%; border: 2px solid black; text-align:center; margin-left: 3%; margin-right: auto; margin-top: 3px; margin-bottom:15px; float: left'><tr><th style='border-bottom: 2px dashed red' colspan='15'><h3 style='margin:0'>Admin List</h3></th></tr>"
        + "<tr><th>ID</th><th>Name</th><th>IP</th><th>Money</th><th>Score</th><th>Kills</th><th>Deaths</th><th>Admin</th><th>VIP</th><th>Status</th><th>Action</th></tr>";
    if (data.Tables[0].Rows.Count != 0)
    {
        foreach (DataRow row in data.Tables[0].Rows)
        {
            count++;
            oac.InnerHtml += "<tr><td> " + row[Database.ID] + "</td><td>" + row[Database.Name] + "</td><td>Confidential" /*+ row[Database.IP]*/ + "</td><td>" + row[Database.Money]
                + "</td><td>" + row[Database.Score] + "</td><td>" + row[Database.Kills] + "</td><td>" + row[Database.Deaths] + "</td><th>" + row[Database.Adminlvl]
                + "</th><td>" + row[Database.Viplvl] + "</td><td>TODO</td><td><a href='OActions.aspx?action=modify&ID=" + row[Database.ID] + "'>Modify</a></td></tr>";
            }
        }
        if (count == 0)
            oac.InnerHtml += "<tr><td colspan='15'>No admins found in the database.</td></tr>";
        count = 0;
        oac.InnerHtml += "</table>";
        data = Database.GetDataOffline("SELECT * FROM " + Database.Table + " WHERE " + Database.Viplvl + "> 0 ORDER BY " + Database.Viplvl + " DESC, " + Database.ID + " ASC");
        oac.InnerHtml += "<table style='width:47%; border: 2px solid black; text-align:center; margin-left: auto; margin-right: 3%; margin-top: 3px; margin-bottom:15px; float: right'><tr><th style='border-bottom: 2px dashed purple' colspan='15'><h3 style='margin:0'>VIP List</h3></th></tr>"
            + "<tr><th>ID</th><th>Name</th><th>IP</th><th>Money</th><th>Score</th><th>Kills</th><th>Deaths</th><th>Admin</th><th>VIP</th><th>Status</th><th>Action</th></tr>";
        if (data.Tables[0].Rows.Count != 0)
        {
            foreach (DataRow row in data.Tables[0].Rows)
            {
                count++;
                oac.InnerHtml += "<tr><td> " + row[Database.ID] + "</td><td>" + row[Database.Name] + "</td><td>Confidential" /*+ row[Database.IP]*/ + "</td><td>" + row[Database.Money]
                    + "</td><td>" + row[Database.Score] + "</td><td>" + row[Database.Kills] + "</td><td>" + row[Database.Deaths] + "</td><td>" + row[Database.Adminlvl]
                    + "</td><th>" + row[Database.Viplvl] + "</th><td>TODO</td><td><a href='OActions.aspx?action=modify&ID=" + row[Database.ID] + "'>Modify</a></td></tr>";
            }
        }
        if (count == 0)
            oac.InnerHtml += "<tr><td colspan='15'>No VIPs found in the database.</td></tr>";
    }
```

Comment: That's some very hard to maintain code. What happened to <asp:Table> ?

Answer (score 0):

It's not a best practice to write HTML code in code behind. But if you want two Tables at the same line you must have this final HTML code in your DOM.

```
    <div id="container" style="width:100%;display:inline">
     <table id="table_one" style="width:47%;Float:left">
      ...
     </table>
     <table id="table_Two" style="width:47%;Float:left">
      ...
     </table>
   </div>
```

Comment: What I posted works in my PC, but it won't be a screen relative size in other devices..

Comment: That's why i notice that the two table must be inside the same container .

Comment: And their widths' sum must be <= their container's width

Comment: I tried that, but same result pops up. In my iPhone it won't resize properly.. And for some reason the tables are more than 50% width.. :o

Comment: so i guess it's an inheritence Css problem.For the width attribute add  !important.                                                                                                     style="width:47%!important"

Comment: Actually I know why it's bigger than 47% width, the problem is the amount of text in the table that makes it larger in smaller screens.. I wish I could fix it somehow though.. Maybe something with Javascript

Comment: Use the css property max-width to limit it

Comment: But then the text will not be written correctly, am I wrong?

Comment: Noramally the height will change